# How to change SEO page title in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, seo

How do can you change the page `<title>` used within the `<head>` tag in Magento 2 with LayoutXML?

In Magento 1 you could use:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setTitle"><title>Example Title</title></action>
</reference>
```

But I can't find a way to do this with M2, so far I've tried...

```
<head>
    <title>Example Title</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 3):

As I've searched, Magento 2 sets the page title in the `Block` classes, more exactly in the `_prepareLayout()` method with the `$this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set($pageTitle)` instruction.

To use the `_prepareLayout()` method and the functionality of `$this->pageConfig` attribute, `Block` classes needs to extend the `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` class.

If you'll take a look in the `__construct(...)` construct of the `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` class, you'll find `$this->pageConfig = $context->getPageConfig();`, which is an instance of `\Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config` class, responsible with a vast majority of SEO stuff methods: `setDescription(), getDescription(), setRobots(), getRobots()` and so on. Also, in this class, you'll find the `getTitle()` method, returning an instance of `\Magento\Framework\View\Page\Title`. This class contains `set($title)` metohd responsible for setting the page title.