# Magento 2 remove breadcrumb empty title category view

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, breadcrumbs, category-view, meta-title

I am developing a custom theme which never displays the breadcrumb, so I removed it in the default.xml:

```
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
```

This caused that the category view page to have empty meta title.
Is there a way to programmatically set the meta title for this type of page?

Comment: check out my answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179743/how-to-change-seo-page-title-in-magento-2/179773#179773

Comment: Interesting.. so, should I include a custom block in the category view page to run that code, right?

Comment: hmm ... yes, in theory it should work... give it a try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the suggestion of Alex Constantinescu in [his answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179743/how-to-change-seo-page-title-in-magento-2/179773#179773) I managed to set the category title in the category view page.

Firstly I created a custom block for this purpose:

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Content\Block;

class Title extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     */
    protected $_registry;

    function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = [],
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_registry = $registry;
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $category = $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
        if($category)
        {
            $category->getMetaTitle();
            $metaTitle = empty($category->getMetaTitle()) ? $category->getName() : $category->getMetaTitle();
            $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set($metaTitle);
        }
    }
}
```

In the `prepareLayout` method I retrieve the current category and set the meta title (if present) or the category name as meta title.

Then I included the block in my `catalog_category_view.xml` file, without specifying a template:

```
<referenceBlock name="main">
    <block name="category.title" class="Custom\Content\Block\Title" />
</referenceBlock>
```